# How to print regexp default variable $1 without variable conflict

Tags: regex, variables, mod-rewrite

Apache regexp is for the most part similar to Perl regexp. How would I convert this Perl version of a regexp, to Apache regexp. mod_rewrite or RedirectMatch

```
RewriteRule ^(de/)*reviews(.*) https://www.rewrite.com/${1}reviews$2 [L,R=301]
```

Perl permits the use of {braces} in variables, to prevent $1reviews being treated as a scalar variable. The above directive would cover both the /root dir, as well as the /de/ dir.

$1 would be empty if matched from the /root dir
$1 would would store de/ if matched from the /de/ dir

Possible?

Comment: as `$1rewrite` is not a valid Perl variable name, it works without curly braces in Perl.

Comment: Erm, I'm trying to achieve ${1} , in place of $1 . However if used like this: $1reviews, apache will think the variable name is "$1reviews" rather than "$1" followed by the "reviews" string. Not having an issue with, address the Apache question.

Comment: That's why I replaced the `perl` tag with `mod-rewrite`.

Comment: Oh, you did that on the quiet. I thought you were trying to help provide a solution.

Comment: Yes, I tried to attract people who know to solution instead of attracting people who don't.

Comment: Actually, `$1` should work as is. If it does not, there are usual workarounds like `${1}` (you tried and it does not work, right?), `\1` (not sure this will work in Apache mode rewrite though), or even `\01`.